# making for loop for character vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, character, stringr

```
char_vector <- c("Africa", "identical", "ending" ,"aa" ,"bb", "rain" ,"Friday" ,"transport") # character vector
```

1. Suppose I have the above character vector
   I would like to create a for loop to print on the screen only the elements in a vector that have more than 5 characters and starts with a vowel
   and also delete from the vector those elements that do not start with a vowel
2. I created this for loop but it also gives null characters

```
for (i in char_vector){
    if (str_length(i) > 5){
    i <- str_subset(i, "^[AEIOUaeiou]")
    print(i)
    
    } 
}
```

3. The result for the above is

```
[1] "Africa"
[1] "identical"
[1] "ending"
character(0)
character(0)
```

4. My desired result would only be the first 3 characters
5. I'm really new to R and facing huge difficulty with creating a for loop for this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `stringr` functions, you'd rather use `str_detect` instead of `str_subset`, and you can take advantage of the fact that those functions are vectorized:

```r
library(stringr)
char_vector[str_length(char_vector) > 5 & str_detect(char_vector, "^[AEIOUaeiou]")]
#[1] "Africa"    "identical" "ending"
```

or if you want your for loop as a single vector:

```r
vec <- c()
for (i in char_vector){
  if (str_length(i) > 5 & str_detect(i, "^[AEIOUaeiou]")){
    vec <- c(vec, i)
  } 
}
vec
# [1] "Africa"    "identical" "ending"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Do you know how to print this as a vector in the for loop?

Comment: Yes, you can see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grepl` with the pattern `^[AEIOUaeiuo]\w{5,}$`:

```r
char_vector <- c("Africa", "identical", "ending" ,"aa" ,"bb", "rain" ,"Friday" ,"transport")
char_vector <- char_vector[grepl("^[AEIOUaeiuo]\\w{5,}$", char_vector)]
char_vector

[1] "Africa"    "identical" "ending"
```

The regex pattern used here says to match words which:

```regex
^             from the start of the word
[AEIOUaeiuo]  starts with a vowel
\w{5,}        followed by 5 or more characters (total length > 5)
$             end of the word
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need for loop, because we use *[vectorized](https://docs.ycrc.yale.edu/r-novice-gapminder/09-vectorization/#:%7E:text=Most%20of%20R%27s%20functions%20are,read%2C%20and%20less%20error%20prone.&text=The%20multiplication%20happened%20to%20each%20element%20of%20the%20vector.)* functions in R.

A simple solution using `grep` and `substr` (refer to [Tim Blegeleisen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72168040/1861328) for details):

```
substr(grep('^[aeiu].{4}', char_vector, T, , T), 1, 3)
# [1] "Afr" "ide" "end"
```

Comment: Nice reminder about the `ignore.case = T` parameter of the `grep()` function :-). If the OP needs the three strings the `substr()` is not necessary: `grep('^[aeiu].{4}', char_vector, T, , T)`

Comment: @Paul I still have feeling that OP needs first three chars, but yeah, `substr()` hear is annoying :)

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 characters?

```r
library(stringr)
for (i in char_vector){
  if (str_length(i) > 5 & str_detect(i, "^[AEIOUaeiou]")) {
    word <- str_sub(i, 1, 3)
    print(word)
    
  } 
}
```

output is:

```
[1] "Afr"
[1] "ide"
[1] "end"
```

Comment: I think the first 3 characters means the first 3 strings here.

Comment: Ok sorry, I just suggested as requested. I leave my answer. Sorry. Ty for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Using only base R functions. No need for a loop. I wrapped the steps in a function so you can use the function with other character vectors. You could make this code shorter ([see @utubun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72168213/10264278)) but I feel it is easier to understand the process with a "one line one step" approach.

```r
char_vector <- c("Africa", "identical", "ending" ,"aa" ,"bb", "rain" ,"Friday" ,"transport")
yourfun <- function(char_vector){
  char_vector <- char_vector[nchar(char_vector)>= 5] # grab only the strings that are at least 5 characters long
  char_vector <- char_vector[grep(pattern = "^[AEIOUaeiou]", char_vector)] # grab strings that starts with vowel
  return(char_vector) # print the first three strings
  # remove comments to get the first three characters of each string
  # out <- substring(char_vector, 1, 3) # select only the first 3 characters of each string
  # return(out)
}
yourfun(char_vector = char_vector)
#> [1] "Africa" "identical" "ending"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>